# Why is there a web process active even if Safari isn't opened?

Tags: macos, safari, spotlight

I noticed that even when Safari is closed, many web processes are active, and these processes are active even when I just restarted my Mac.

Actually, I noticed that this process is in the Spotlight web content group, what is the purpose of it and when will it stop ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it perhaps a Dashboard widget? That looks like a news site, so perhaps a news ticker widget?

Comment: I don't have any dashboard widget, and many websites are concerned, but never all of them at once.
**But as I mentioned, this seems to be linked to Spotlight.**

Comment: Is this website perhaps in your Reading List within Safari? Perhaps Spotlight is used to index the content of your Safari Reading List.

Comment: No, I checked and this website isn't in my reading list.

Answer (score 26):

I noticed that too, and did the following to "solve the problem" (it's not a problem for some people though :P ):

In **System Preferences**, open **Spotlight**. In **Search Results** tab, disable **Bookmarks & History**. Then restart. After that, Safari Web Content process won't be active when Safari is not open.

Comment: But I think we should probably wait till it stops, apart if it never does...

Comment: Wow. I thought I had disabled all of them (Bing, Suggestions, etc) but I never would have guessed this one. Thank you!